# Windows 7 Ultimate failed install

Tags: windows-7, installation

I'm upgrading from Windows 7 Enterprise (which was actually upgraded from Windows 7 Ultimate 3 months ago) back to Windows 7 Ultimate (32-bit Enterprise to 32-bit Ultimate). After 4 hours or so, the install fails with the message "This version of Windows could not be installed. Your previous version of Windows has been restored, and you can continue to use it." This error is back at my Enterprise desktop, there's no error that I could see during install, just a message indicating that it was reverting everything. Oh and my monitor wouldn't start after the PC rebooted again. After another reboot I could see it was reverting everything.

I tracked down the error logs and here's the files (from C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther):

http://www.mediafire.com/?9sz9p41a535lpq3 - setupact.log

http://www.mediafire.com/?7sez5k5nja7f78p - setupmem.dmp

I know a fresh install is best, but I'm hoping to avoid that because I'd need a new hard drive.

Comment: The setuperr.log is here if you need it (the website wouldn't let me link more than 2 files) : http://www.mediafire.com/?aptvkbiw1kpglfb - setuperr.log

Comment: "ultimate failed install" - that just struck me as funny :)

Comment: @ClaudiuD.Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have a driver plugin that is causing it

[0x0808fe] MIG    Plugin {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}: BthMig: Failed to migrate bthport keys, bailing out

EDIT:

Run the W7 upgrade advisor and see what it says. If it flags any program or driver, remove them before upgrading.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=1b544e90-7659-4bd9-9e51-2497c146af15

Comment: From what I can see, it's a bluetooth driver. I do not own a bluetooth device onboard or plugged in my PC, that file is perfectly useless. Can I just delete it? Also, how do I do that? Also, W7 Upgrade Advisor says that except for one program I just uninstalled, everything is ok.

Comment: Is this a notebook?

Comment: No, it's my desktop.

Comment: Check my edit above..

Comment: Well, the only drivers that would cause errors are the ATI video driver and the Catalyst Control Center, also from ATI

Comment: Nope, uninstalled ATI Drivers, still error...here's the error logs:

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/?55kv4n8hmaai11h . Also, I plugged in a VGA cable instead of a DVI one, read somewhere it would help but to no avail.

Comment: All I can suggest is to do a clean install at this point, sorry. I suspect malware or registry corruption.

Comment: Okay then, let me scan for Malware and clean up my registry and I'll try again.

Comment: Nope...didn't work... http://www.mediafire.com/?k40chcdhsc5oj2g

Comment: Time for a clean install.

Comment: Sigh...I guess...then I'll have to research how to backup my registry so I don't have to reinstall everything. Kinda like http://www.optimizingpc.com/install/backupdata.html or something